# Meaning of $\land$ (other than logical and)

Tags: notation

Any idea what $\land$ means in the below formula?

$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^S p_i \land \sqrt{\frac{e^\epsilon p_i}{n}} \right)^2
$$

Here, $S \in \mathbb{N}$ is a natural number, $p_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are probability estimates, $\epsilon \in [0,\infty)$ is a non-negative real number, $e$ is the mathematical constant, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a number of samples.

I have seen this in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10335.pdf) (e.g., Equation 5), and [another version](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8512-minimax-optimal-estimation-of-approximate-differential-privacy-on-neighboring-databases.pdf) of the same paper also contains it (e.g., Algorithm 1). The latter paper also contains

$$
0 \lor \left(1 \land \sum_{i=1}^S \delta_i \right).
$$

I would usually expect $\land$ to mean logical and, but that does not really seem appropriate here.

Comment: $a\wedge  b$ denotes the minimum between $a$ and $b$ and $a\vee b$ denotes the maximum between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used for minimum and maximum.

$a \vee b$ = maximum of $a$ and $b$.

$a \wedge b$ = minimum of $a$ and $b$.

The notation comes from lattice theory (think of the maximum *moving down* from infinity until it hits one of $a$ or $b$ and likewise for the minimum *moving up*), but is surprisingly common in probability theory.